# Using a for loop to read ONLY 5 numbers and average them. JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop, average

Really having issues with this program I'm making. I've searched this site and a few others, although have yet to find a solution. It may look like I'm just soliciting help but I truly am stuck. I am to make a program that reads in 5 numbers from the user and average those numbers. My extent of knowledge of Java is the Scanner class and for loops, yet haven't used while loops yet. Here is the very poorly written code:

```
public class Average5
{
   public static void main(String args[])
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int num;

   System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
   num = sc.nextInt();

   for(int num1 = 0; num1 <= num; num1++)
   {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
   }
```

I honestly have no clue what to do. More or less self taught.

Comment: Its generally recommended,at stackoverflow, that your question should contain more details about specifically went wrong or what was the expected result vs what did you actually get

Comment: And general programming tip, try to avoid reusing variables like you do `num`. That will lead to bugs, as it does here

Comment: Is the first number you enter meant to be the number of subsequent numbers to average? or is it always 5?

Comment: Sorry. Just starting out. I read that 'i' makes a better choice. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: It is supposed to always be 5.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html - read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Average5 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int numlenngth = 5;
        double total = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int num1 = 0; num1 < numlenngth; num1++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            total += sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Average : " + (total / numlenngth));

    }
}
```

output >>

```
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 2
Average : 1.2
```

Comment: It will not give exact average as you are using int.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate total is double .this gives exact average .if you enter 1,1,1,1,2 average gives as  1.2 but if total was a int you will get 1 instead 1.2

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that

Comment: Yes, but one thing. You have hard coded the numlength 5, hence not generic solution :)

Comment: @ShoaibChikate "using for lop to read only 5 numbers " that's why i hard coded it.do you wanna take loop time from user?do you wanna ask from user how much numbers do you wanna read and then user hit 5 or other???

Answer (score 0):

For calculating exact average, you need to take double(sum) instead of int and add(sum) everytime with the user value.

```
public class Average5
{
   public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please enter how many numbers you want to enter for calculating average: ");
   int totalCount = sc.nextInt();
   double sum=0;

   for(int i= 0; i<totalCount; i++)
   {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        sum += sc.nextDouble();
   }

   System.out.println("Average of number is"+(sum/totalCount));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the array to store the numbers:

```
public class Average5 {
    private static final int MAX = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[MAX];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please type the number");
            numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        float average = getAverage(numbers);
        System.out.println("The average of the five numbers: " + average);
    }

    public static float getAverage(int[] arg0) {
        int sum = 0;
        float Ret = 0.0f;

        if(arg0 != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            sum += arg0[i];

            Ret = sum / MAX;
        }

        return Ret;
    }
}
```

This is not the only way to slove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same as the others posted, but it is limited to entering only 5 numbers and it takes care of possibly resulting floating number in the final division:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average5 {

    private static final int TOTAL = 5;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 0;

        System.out.format("You have to enter %d numbers now.\n", TOTAL);

        for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= TOTAL; cnt++) {
            System.out.format("Please enter number %d of %d: ", cnt, TOTAL);
            sum += scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.format("The average is %f.\n", sum / TOTAL);
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int num = 0;
float total = 0f;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
num = sc.nextInt();

for(int num1 = 0; num1 <= num; num1++)
   {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        total += sc.nextInt();
   }

System.out.println("Average : "+(total/num));
```

Comment: `total/num` is typed as an integer, not ideal for an average.

Comment: This only allows me to enter in 3 numbers then the program ends.

Comment: also variable naming could be better.

Comment: first number gets the how much number do you want to receive from user.